# Creating pandas series from a list eats up ram

Tags: python, pandas, memory-management, google-colaboratory

I am reading a list of numbers as strings from a txt file. It's not a big file, only 1 GB. Then  the numbers are converted to float and put in a list.

```
with open(...) as f:
    lines = f.read()
mylist = [float(x) for x in lines if x not in ['[',']',',', ' ']]
```

the end contents of my list are just simple floats in 1.0 format. However this takes up a lot of ram. I noticed if I convert them to int they don't take up as much space, but I need them to be float.

Then when I try to convert this to a pandas series my whole session crashes.

```
mylist = pd.Series(mylist)
```

I am using google colab with roughly 25 GB of ram and 15 GB of GPU. I can't believe only 1 GB of data can eat up 25 GB of ram, I must be doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what I should do. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try creating dataframe directly from txt using ```df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep=" ", header=None)```. See how this works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to use the standard method (with custom delimiter) to open this file?

```
import pandas as pd
df  = pd.read_csv('you_file.txt', delimiter='\t')
df = df[(df['some_column'] != '[') & (df['some_column'] != ']')]
df = df[(df['some_column'] != ',') & (df['some_column'] != ' ')]
```

**UPD**:
Maybe you can try to use a python generator, it is a great tool when we care about RAM.

```
def open_file():
    for row in open(file_name, "r"):
        yield row
lines = open_file()
```

Comment: Hi, while this did not fix my problem, I was able to write a pandas read_csv method like this . `df  = pd.read_csv('a.txt', sep = ",", header=None).T.replace(['\[','\]'], ['',''], regex=True).astype(float)` but it still crashes my colab after eating up all the ram

Comment: Try to use what was written in upd section, maybe it will help you...

Comment: Also, pandas default is float64, you can roughly halve the memory requirements by using `pd.read_csv(..., dtype=np.float32, ...)`